# Why is a Lisp file not a list of statements?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I've been learning Scheme through the Little Schemer book and it strikes me as odd that a file in Scheme / Lisp isn't a list of statements. I mean, everything is supposed to be a list in Lisp, but a file full of statements doesn't look like a list to me. Is it represented as a list underneath? Seems odd that it isn't a list in the file.

For instance...

```
#lang scheme

(define atom?
    (lambda (x)
    (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))))

(define sub1
    (lambda (x y)
    (- x y)))

(define add1
    (lambda (x y)
    (+ x y)))

(define zero?
    (lambda (x)
    (= x 0)))
```

Each define statement is a list, but there is no list of define statements.

Comment: You can assume a program is wrapped with `(begin statement ...)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22361111/1193075

Comment: What advantage would that give? Would that make Lisp programming easier or more difficult? What do you think?

Comment: Besides definitions, which today could be in a library you import, an idiomatic Scheme program file would have one expression. BTW: `#lang scheme` is not scheme, but synonym for `#lang racket`. To get Scheme you need to use `#!r6rs` or `#!r5rs` (which might be better for the little Schemer). You can also select R5RS as a legacy language in the bottom left dropdown and then you need to remove `#lang...` or `#!..`.

Comment: No, not everything is supposed to be a list in Lisp.  Please don't continue to spread that myth.

Answer (score 2):

It is not, because there is no practical reasons for it. In fact, series of `define` statements change internal state of the language. Information about the state can be accessible via functions. For example , you can ask Lisp if some symbol is bound to a function.

There is no practical benefit in traversing all entered forms (for example, `define` forms). I suppose that this approach (all statements are elements of a list) would lead to code that would be hard to read.

Also, I think it not quite correct to think that "everything is supposed to be a list in Lisp", since there are also some atomic types, which are quite self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate a form, if the form defines something, that definition is added to the environment, and that environment is (or can be) a single list. You can build a program without using files, by just typing definitions into the REPL. In Lisp as in any language, the program “lives” in the run-time environment, not the source files.